# Execution timed out (12000ms) kata Generate Numbers from Digits #2 on Code Wars (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Could you give me a hint where the time consuming part of this code is?
It's my temporary solutions for the kata Generate Numbers from Digits #2 from codewars.com.
Thanks!

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations


def proc_arrII(arr):
    length = Counter(arr).most_common()[-1][1]
    b = [''.join(x) for x in list(set(permutations(arr,length)))]
    max_count = [max(Counter(x).values()) for x in b]

    total = 0
    total_rep = 0
    maximum_pandigit = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        total+=1
        if max_count[i] > 1:
            total_rep+=1
        elif int(b[i]) > maximum_pandigit:
            maximum_pandigit = int(b[i])
    if maximum_pandigit == 0:
        return([total])
    else:
        return([total,total_rep,maximum_pandigit])
```

Answer (score 0):

When posting this,
it would have been helpful to offer example input,
or link to the [original question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/584e936ae82520a397000027),
or include some `python -m cProfile` [output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual).

Here is a minor item, it inflates the running time very very slightly.
In the expression `[''.join(x) for x in list(set(permutations(arr, length)))]`
there's no need to call `list( ... )`.
The `join` just needs an iterable, and a `set` works fine for that.

Here is a bigger item.
`permutations` already [makes the promise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) that
"if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each permutation."
Seems like you want to dedup (with `set( ... )`) on the way in,
rather than on the way out,
for an algorithmic win -- reduced complexity.

The rest looks nice enough.
You might try benching without the `elif` clause,
using the expression `max(map(int, b))` instead.
If there's any gain it would only be minor,
turning O(n) into O(n) with slightly smaller coefficient.
Similarly, you should just assign `total = len(b)` and be done with it,
no need to increment it that many times.